How to enable admin RPC for solana-validator?
i want to call admin RPC methods, eg. "method": "rpcAddress" on the validator, however i'm only getting method not found erros. How to enable admin RPC methods on the validator?
solana-validator 1.18.18

The admin RPC server is an IPC server, not an HTTP server: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/32e8ad2149a9e1af9c67defd342140707629a256/validator/src/admin_rpc_service.rs#L6
It appears that it's only accessible through a file on disk, listening to the admin_rpc_path file https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/32e8ad2149a9e1af9c67defd342140707629a256/validator/src/admin_rpc_service.rs#L762
All of the functions should be available already -- you can try solana-validator exit to test. It'll connect to the admin RPC service and run the exit command: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/32e8ad2149a9e1af9c67defd342140707629a256/validator/src/main.rs#L649-L686
